# How to display previous month and year value in unix

Tags: date, unix

I required previous month and year value in a variable in Unix . I am not able to find any correct unix command for that.
Meanwhile I have achieved this requirement through sql command, in ext variable and used it.

```
ext=`sqlplus -s user/pass <<END
set feedback off set pagesize 0
select to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Mon-YYYY') from dual;
exit;
END>>`
```

But I was looking if I can achieve this by unix command in which I can get same result as Aug-2016.
Most close I have got through unix command is by
ext=`date + %b-%Y`
which is giving me current month year value as Sep-2016.
But I require previous month value and in same format.Can anyone suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `date -d` ?

```
% date -d '1 month ago' '+%b-%Y'       
Aug-2016
```

Comment: Sadly, `date -d` is a GNUism.